# How do I install/run Hipku using Linux (links in the details)

Tags: javascript, installation, kali-linux

I received a hacker challenge gift for Christmas. I'm no hacker, nor do I work in an IT role, but I'm trying my best. I've got a haiku:

> The weary red dove fights in the empty tundra. Jasmine petals dance.

I need to convert this into an IP.

I'm 100% sure I'm supposed to install/run a program called Hipku.

https://github.com/gabemart/hipku

The installation instructions read:
"Install with `npm install hipku`. index.js can also be used directly in the browser."

However, I just don't have the skills necessary to get this to work for me.

I'm using kali linux virtualised on a mac, and I've ran this command (`npm install hipku`) in a shell.
The next step from the example is:
`Hipku.decode('The weary red dove\nfights in the empty tundra.\nJasmine petals dance.');`
However, I get this message

`└─$ Hipku.decode('The weary red dove fights in the empty tundra. Jasmine petals dance.'); zsh: unknown file attribute: h`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

pps. I've found this webpage of someone running through the steps of the entire challenge, but when it comes to the step of decoding the haiku, it's not helpful (for me!)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You installed a library that you need to run BUT there is an easier way: go to [v6decode](https://v6decode.com/), right click "inspect element", you should now be on a new windows, go to the "console" tab. from there enter the line and press enter.
I've tested for you and got 254.53.93.114.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Can you (for my own knowledge) explain why I needed to use that v6decode webpage to achive this?

Comment: It's just a website that is using the hipku library. You could have use any other website that use this lib, or run your own.